# React native android build is failing after configured kotlin-gradle-plugin, kotlin-android and kotlin-android-extensions

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, expo

I implemented AWS chime into my react native project. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-react-native-demo) I had to add below configs into my project.

`build.gradle` file changes

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

`app/build.gradle` file changes

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

When I configured these changes and after `yarn android` (build) my build is failing with `.kt` file error in `node_modules`.

```
e: /projects/rndemo/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (27, 9): Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T> emptyList(): List<T>
Please specify it explicitly.

e: /projects/rndemo/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (48, 12): Type inference failed: fun <T, A> invokeDelegateMethod(name: String, argTypes: Array<Class<*>>, args: Array<A>): T
cannot be applied to
(String,Array<Class<*>>,Array<String?>)
```

Without above configuration changes application works fine.

What is the reason for this ?

Is there a way to skip node modules being compiled with specified kotlin version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by updating kotlin version i.e. to `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'`