# cannot install Drawer Navigator. No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, aar, react-native-reanimated

I want to install Drawer Navigator     https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator     version 6.x
first install

```
yarn add @react-navigation/drawer
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin',],
};
```

then run
`react-native run-android`

errors:   Configure project :react-native-reanimated No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.  I clone my project multiple time and test different similar solution. but ...

**first solution:**
.\gradlew build --warning-mode all

**second solution:**
cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew :app:bundleRelease

./gradlew -v

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-08-05 21:17:56 UTC
Revision:     d1daa0cbf1a0103000b71484e1dbfe096e095918

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          11.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.2+9-LTS)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

[Output in Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO3Cx.jpg)

[android->build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqG2U.jpg)

[run command --warning - mode all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCNFi.jpg)

---

Finally, I can run project.

[Build successful but show no AAR for react native-reanimated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcE1B.jpg)

First, install the package according to the version mentioned in the issue.
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/11391

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "6.3.16",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.10.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.3",
    "react-native-screens": "3.20.0"
  },
```

After that, according the
[React native android build is failing after configured kotlin-gradle-plugin, kotlin-android and kotlin-android-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904067/react-native-android-build-is-failing-after-configured-kotlin-gradle-plugin-kot)

resolved the issue by adding kotlin version.

```
build.gradle file changes
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.8.20'
        ...
        }
 dependencies {
        ...
        classpath ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
    }
```

but sill no aar

```
node_modules->react-native-reanimated->android
there is no react-native-reanimate.aar
```

[node_modules path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MsSm.jpg)